# Unity Xcode Build Succeed but app not opening

Tags: unity-game-engine, xcode11

I have unity project which works Android platforms perfectly. When I am trying to build IOS version everything succeeds but game not start I have bunch of error codes like this.

> 2020-11-24 12:11:12.653727+0300 okeymuhabbet[10375:105001] FCM:
> Loading UIApplication FIRFCM category 2020-11-24 12:11:12.885008+0300
> okeymuhabbet[10375:105001] Built from '2020.1/release' branch, Version
> '2020.1.3f1 (cf5c4788e1d8)', Build type 'Development', Scripting
> Backend 'il2cpp' 2020-11-24 12:11:12.916298+0300
> okeymuhabbet[10375:105001] Setting up iOS 10 message delegate.
> -> applicationDidFinishLaunching() PlayerConnection initialized from /Users/dncmedya/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1C0CA52B-70B6-451C-A454-6A248EB587A3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/931BBAD5-D2C1-4AC4-9454-3859D264AD40/okeymuhabbet.app/Data
> (debug = 0) PlayerConnection initialized network socket : 0.0.0.0
> 55000 Multi-casting "[IP] 192.168.1.83 [Port] 55000 [Flags] 2 [Guid]
> 3804626205 [EditorId] 2769426335 [Version] 1048832 [Id]
> iPhonePlayer(dnc-macbook-pro):56000 [Debug] 0 [PackageName]
> iPhonePlayer [ProjectName] Okey Muhabbet" to [225.0.0.222:54997]...
> Started listening to [0.0.0.0:55000] PlayerConnection already
> initialized - listening to [0.0.0.0:55000] 2020-11-24
> 12:11:13.032852+0300 okeymuhabbet[10375:105001] Metal GPU Frame
> Capture Enabled 2020-11-24 12:11:13.033272+0300
> okeymuhabbet[10375:105001] Metal API Validation Enabled 2020-11-24
> 12:11:13.172375+0300 okeymuhabbet[10375:106050] 6.24.0 -
> [I-ACS031025] Analytics screen reporting is enabled.
> Call +[FIRAnalytics setScreenName:setScreenClass:] to set the screen
> name or override the default screen class name. To disable screen
> reporting, set the flag FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean)
> in the Info.plist 2020-11-24 12:11:13.189584+0300
> okeymuhabbet[10375:105001] FBSDKLog: starting with Graph API v2.4, GET
> requests for /341409100047379/model_asset should contain an explicit
> "fields" parameter
> -> applicationDidBecomeActive() 2020-11-24 12:11:13.214862+0300 okeymuhabbet[10375:106050] [Client] Updating selectors failed with:
> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service
> on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was
> invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service
> on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was
> invalidated.} 2020-11-24 12:11:13.215554+0300
> okeymuhabbet[10375:106050] [Client] Updating selectors after delegate
> addition failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The
> connection to service on pid 0 named
> com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated."
> UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named
> com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.} 2020-11-24
> 12:11:13.216339+0300 okeymuhabbet[10375:106048] [Client] Synchronous
> remote object proxy returned error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain
> Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 0 named
> com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated."
> UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named
> com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.} GfxDevice:
> creating device client; threaded=1 2020-11-24 12:11:13.220218+0300
> okeymuhabbet[10375:106048] [Client] Synchronous remote object proxy
> returned error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The
> connection to service on pid 0 named
> com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated."
> UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named
> com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.} Initializing
> Metal device caps: Apple iOS simulator GPU 2020-11-24
> 12:11:13.222235+0300 okeymuhabbet[10375:105450] [Client] Updating
> selectors failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The
> connection to service on pid 0 named
> com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated."
> UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named
> com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.} 2020-11-24
> 12:11:13.224354+0300 okeymuhabbet[10375:106048] [Client] Synchronous
> remote object proxy returned error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain
> Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 0 named
> com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated."
> UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named
> com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.} 2020-11-24
> 12:11:13.225103+0300 okeymuhabbet[10375:105450] [Client] Updating
> selectors failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The
> connection to service on pid 0 named
> com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated."
> UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named
> com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.} Initialize
> engine version: 2020.1.3f1 (cf5c4788e1d8) 2020-11-24
> 12:11:13.506559+0300 okeymuhabbet[10375:106019] [plugin]
> AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID
> 0x6000034665e0> F8BB1C28-BAE8-11D6-9C31-00039315CD46 2020-11-24
> 12:11:14.154104+0300 okeymuhabbet[10375:106189]
> HALB_IOBufferManager_Client::GetIOBuffer: the stream index is out of
> range 2020-11-24 12:11:14.154313+0300 okeymuhabbet[10375:106189]
> HALB_IOBufferManager_Client::GetIOBuffer: the stream index is out of
> range 2020-11-24 12:11:14.166547+0300 okeymuhabbet[10375:106189]
> [aqme] AQME.h:254:IOProcFailure: AQDefaultDevice (1): output stream 0:
> null buffer 2020-11-24 12:11:14.166884+0300 okeymuhabbet[10375:106189]
> [aqme] AQMEIO_HAL.cpp:1774:IOProc: EXCEPTION thrown (-50): error != 0
> 2020-11-24 12:11:22.545311+0300 okeymuhabbet[10375:105001] Start: Mach
> message timeout. Apparently deadlocked. Aborting now. (lldb)

I tried lots of things to fix but...

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue.
Installed last version of Xcode and updated cocoapods for my project, changed nothing at unity side. Now my app works perfectly.